# Topology on the real line 2

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

"$A\subset \Bbb{R}$ is said *convex* if for all $x,y\in A$ and $0\leq\lambda\leq1$ then $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in A$. Show that a subset $C$ of $\Bbb{R}$ is convex if, and only if, $C$ is an interval."
The part $\Leftarrow$ of the "if and only if" is very easy. The trouble is the $\Rightarrow$ implication :( ...
Some hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that if $x,y\in A$ and $x<z<y$ then $z\in A.$